# Make a specific content-type inaccessible

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content-types that only is linked from nodes of other content types and therefore should not be directly accessible. In other words, I don't want a visitor to be able to access these kind of nodes by going to `node/<nid>`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module was built for exactly that:

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when en entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.

It's highly configurable and works seamlessly in my experience.

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment? I'm not sure you understood the question, this module was created to solve the exact problem stated by the OP

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down-voted, but it seems to perfectly suit the OP's needs. It could be excessive to install a module just to avoid nodes of a single content type are directly visible, but the OP could need to block the direct access to more than one content type. Also, if the OP is not able to write a module, this is the only alternative.

Comment: @Clive - I just installed `rabbithole` and set it to display `not found` for my content-type but I can still access the node using `node/<nid>`, am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When you edit an individual node of that type what are its settings for rabbit hole? Maybe the default settings didn't filter down to those nodes. There'll be a pretty simple query to fix that, I can throw something together if that is the problem so let me know

Comment: I haven't used rabbit hole, but it's not just that you're user 1 and the restriction gets ignored?
@kiamlaluno RH is not the only alternative. As I posted in my answer, PM can do it to, and everyone already has ctools on their sites which may make PM preferable.

Comment: @Letharion - I was logged in and was viewing the site as administrator, thanks for pointing this one out for me, could have spent a whole night ripping my hair=)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the access callback used for node/%node, for example using code similar to the following one. Create a module (if you don't have already a custom one), and add the following code to the .module file.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['node/%node'])) {
    $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_access_callback';
  }
}

function mymodule_node_access_callback($op, $node) {
  if (in_array($node->type, $content_types_that_should_not_be_directly_accessible_array)) {
    // Leave the node accessible to the users with the permission of administering nodes, or who can bypass the node access.
    return (user_access('administer nodes') || user_access('bypass node access'));
  }
  else {
    return node_access($op, $node);
  }
}
```

I would use a custom module, if you need this functionality only on few content types, if you don't need all the functionality provided by a third-party module, or you want to be able to customize the code to use.

In the other case, I would rather use a third-party module, such as [the one suggested](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/54819/199) from [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive).

Comment: A couple of small editions to that...1. you need to determine the node type with `$type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;`, it won't always be an object. 2. There's a 3rd parameter, `$account` that should be passed in and used in the call to `user_access()` for flexibility. 3. you should return `NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW`, `NODE_ACCESS_DENY` or `NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE`, a boolean value will probably work but it's safest to keep to the constants :)

Comment: When a node is being viewed, the access callback gets a node object; the node type is passed on node creation (`$op == 'create'`), since the node is still to be created. The third parameter is not passed to the access callback when it called as access callback for node/%node (its access arguments are `array('view', 1)`) but when the access callback is used as normal function. [node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7) returns `TRUE`, or `FALSE`.

Comment: `node_access()` has an optional 3rd parameter, sure, but `hook_node_access()` (different function) is **always** passed the `$account` parameter and it should always be used. Have a look at the code for `node_access()`, it also checks the return from `module_invoke_all()` against the predefined constants so those must be used. Just look at the docs for `hook_node_access()`, the example is pretty clear. The return value is clearly specified as one of the `NODE_ACCESS_*` constants. The fact that you're testing `$node->type` and not checking the `$op` means you're likely to get errors

Comment: Trust me, I've implemented this hook hundreds of times and I've managed to invoke every error possible out of it. The docs really must be followed or you'll get errors later on

Comment: I've only just noticed you're using that function as a menu callback, so all you need to is change the name of the callback function to avoid the naming collision with `hook_node_access()` and it'll be fixed. If it's left as an implementation of `hook_node_access()`, though, it will break things because the function signature and return values are incorrect

Comment: That's correct: I am not implementing `hook_node_access()`, but changing the access callback for node/%node. I just chose an unhappy name for my access callback. `:)`

Comment: Awesome :) Shall we clear these comments up? Can't have people thinking the mods around here argue over code ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) to deny access or redirect users that try to directly access a certain content type.

If you take a look at my answer in this question [What's the difference between Page manager and Panels?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35186/whats-the-difference-between-page-manager-and-panels), you'll see I take exactly your use case as an example for why one would want to use Page manger.