# CiviCRM Profile form buttons showing but not linked in Drupal profile

Tags: users, civicrm

We are using CiviCRM profiles to allow members to update addition information. We have marked these profile forms in CiviCRM as 'View/Edit Drupal Account' and 'Drupal User Registration. The buttons appear (and disappear if you remove these settings) in the user profile editing screens. When the buttons are clicked on the user is taken to their Drupal profile, not the screens to capture the CiviCRM data as per this screen shot.

[image: Demographics Link, links back to Drupal profile]

This was working on this site. What changed? We did a general drupal upgrade. Drupal 7.19, CiviCRM 4.2.

Thanks
Interlated

Comment: We found that the menu_router database table had page_callback set to 'page_manager_user_edit_page' and include_file set to 'sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/page_manager/plugins/tasks/user_edit.inc' in it rather than drupal_get_form and user.pages.inc. We can change the database and it works, although rebuild menus and it goes back.

Comment: would you please give us a "commit" click at the [CiviCRM SE site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2) so we can have a dedicated space for these questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you found in the menu_router table, perhaps Page Manager is throwing a spanner in the works here? There's a good post about Page Manager here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/35187/38865

Comment: The reason was that ctools was upgraded. The module ctool-page-manager keeps changing the 'context' information in the page manager as described. We created a bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2393965.

7.x-1.2 is the most recent version of ctools that works.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but try opening the Advanced field set at the bottom of the Edit Profile Settings page, and deselect requiring creation of Drupal user account. You might get more responses if you posted more info on the fields in the profile, for example, what you expect to see.