# Subpages in Panels like Drupal Blocks using section/*

Tags: panels

I want to manage a page with subpages in panels. I thought the url path setting like section/* will also work in panels like with normal Drupal Blocks. For example i want to ad a menu pane with links to some views like section/myview . The user go to this link and the panel page is gone because it dont check that is a subpage. How can i manage this?

Comment: I don't really follow what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want Panels to generate a page per view?

Comment: Going back to the start of the question, "section/*" doesn't mean anything to Panels. (Page manager, to be precise). The thing that makes PM+P awesome is that * needs to be a _context_, which allows panels to work it's magic. I don't know if it helps, but you might want to take a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35186/whats-the-difference-between-page-manager-and-panels

Comment: Sorry for making confusion. In other words, i want PM to react on all url that begins with e.g. "section" and also all other urls after that e.g. "section/custommenulink". I just want using panes that stay like normal drupal blocks over the "namespace" while i would render one pane the normal drupal $content output. Oh i hope the confusion has not grown :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have time to explain in detail, but the short answer is that you either cant or shouldn't be doing that. You'll need to read up on how path arguments are handled.