# How to display a view on a customize way?

Tags: views, blocks

I've searched similar questions but I'm not sure to have understood how to do it. I would like to create a page for the team of my website. I have several blocs: administrators, moderators, etc.

I'd like to display in a left column the member avatar and on the right, I want to display all the rest of the data such as the nickname, a short description, etc.

If you have any tips on how to search on Stack Exchange, I'd gladly accept the information.

Comment: I found [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) but I don't know if it's the thing I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) is what you're looking for. Panels, in a gist, is similar to how the core Structure -> Block Layout works, except it's more powerful. You use it in conjunction with Page Manager, a submodule of [Ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) (if I remember correctly) which lets you create one-off pages as well as override how core pages render. [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/35186/57572) will explain what which does.

In summary, the workflow would be like this:

1. Create a content type for your members. Populate it with fields for the data.
2. Enable both Panels and Page Manager
3. Go to Structure -> Pages and enable the Node View page (the one with the `/node/%` path)
4. Edit the Node View page and add a *variant* - a config for what to render where, when and how when on the page's path.
5. Configure the variant to render when viewing the content type. I think that's under Selection, then add a Type criteria matching the content type.
6. Configure the layout of the variant. By default, there's a 1-column layout available. You can use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to provide more layouts or you can write your own.
7. Configure the contents of the variant. Here's where the magic happens. You can virtually add *anything* to the layout. Views, blocks, fields, nodes, entire pages, anything. In this case, position the fields of the content type into where you want them.

That's a quick rundown of how to use Panels. And all of this happens with minimal to no coding at all (except if you create your own layout and/or add a sprinkle of CSS so things don't look very Drupal-y).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! You mentionned the Blocks Layout but I never understood how this works. Is it possible to do the same thing without using Panels or is it a "obliged" modules on most Drupal projects?

Comment: @Helmasaur The other way to do it is via template overrides, which can get ugly fast. Also, if you simply want to provide a layout for content type fields, Display Suite or Field Groups (with Bootstrap Field Groups for grids) could do that. But Panels is a handy module to learn if you want greater flexibility. Once you get the hang of it, you will never look back.

Comment: I'm a bit scared to use modules because if it's not updated, I would get stuck with my data. I'm new with a CMS and I'm used to develop my website myself and deciding how to display pages the way I want. The most difficult thing in my opinion is to get to what you want from a "limited" tool. When I say limited, it's that you can't do it the way you want or think but do it with the possibilities that the CMS gives. I need to learn more!

Comment: It's extremely easy to use Views or Paragraphs.